# '/product/app/TrichromeLibrary/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome.so (offset 0x67c000)' ,a Android webview crash exception

Tags: android, video, webview

here is my debug report:

```
signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT), fault addr 0xd1a9b6aa
2020-01-13 15:43:11.560 23186-23186/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: '[FATAL:jni_android.cc(249)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
    '
2020-01-13 15:43:11.560 23186-23186/? A/DEBUG:     r0  00000000  r1  00000000  r2  7fffffff  r3  00000000
2020-01-13 15:43:11.560 23186-23186/? A/DEBUG:     r4  0000004f  r5  ffea2b34  r6  d3225608  r7  d31f0bf8
2020-01-13 15:43:11.560 23186-23186/? A/DEBUG:     r8  ffea26dc  r9  ffea2b2c  r10 ffea2b30  r11 ffea26dc
2020-01-13 15:43:11.560 23186-23186/? A/DEBUG:     ip  ffea26a0  sp  ffea26c8  lr  f2c61461  pc  d1a9b6aa
2020-01-13 15:43:11.561 23186-23186/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2020-01-13 15:43:11.561 23186-23186/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 0194c6aa  /product/app/TrichromeLibrary/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome.so (offset 0x67c000) (BuildId: 83d53232d7c9ce7e2b28c4d2fbbb906cbd90597d)
```

A crash happened when I try to play a video on WebView.
Most crash log are seem like not very useful.but I got this too:

```
2020-01-13 15:43:11.339 22733-22733/com.mi.oa:plugin E/om.mi.oa:plugi:No package ID 02 found for ID 0x02060059.
```

What is the package of ID 02?

Comment: Are you using any Ads like banners ?